# Como puedo indicar dos o mas parámetros en una ruta en django

Tags: python, django, web, aplicación-web, django-urls

Los pongo en contexto de mi problema, estoy desarrollando una pagina web con la versión 1.11 de django. Estoy intentando crear una ruta que recibe 2 parámetros o variables get

Esta es la url que tengo definida en el archivo **urls.py**

```
url(r'^(?P<idiom>[a-z]{2})/(?P<pagename>[a-z]{10})/$', redirect, name="redirect"),
```

Y así tengo definido los parámetros en la función **redirect**

```
def redirect(request, idiom="es", pagename="home"):
```

Pero el error me lo indica que esta en como estoy indicando los dos parámetros que recibe la ruta en el template

```
<a href="{% url 'redirect' es home %}">Home</a>
```

Esto es lo que me sale cuando cargo la pagina

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A parte de eso me dice que

> Error during template rendering
>
> Reverse for 'redirect' with arguments '('', '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P[a-z]{2})/(?P[a-z]{10})/$']

Y me señala en rojo la linea de codigo donde tengo el **Anchor** con la ruta que les indique anteriormente.

Es claro que el error ocurre porque no esta encontrando los dos parametros que se supone recibe esa ruta, pero no se como indicarlos en el **Anchor**

Answer (score 1):

Ya encontré la solución a mi problema, tenia dos errores:

El primer error estaba al definir la expresión regular de la ruta, porque esta diciendo que exactamente el parámetro **pagename** tendría 10 caracteres, cuando en realidad 10 seria el máximo de caracteres, lo solucione colocándole una coma antes del 10 (para indicar que puede tener de 0 a 10 caracteres)

```
url(r'^(?P<idiom>[a-z]{2})/(?P<pagename>[a-z]{,10})/$', redirect, name="redirect"),
```

En este caso no tuve que hacer lo mismo para el parámetro **idiom** porque ese exentamente debe tener 2 caracteres.

El segundo error estaba en como le indicaba los parámetros a la ruta en el **Anchor** porque estos deben estar dentro de comillas simples, de la siguiente forma

```
<a href="{% url 'redirect' 'es' 'home' %}">Home</a>
```

Espero que esto les sirva de ayuda si pasan por lo mismo que yo.